# Time consuming in Regular Expression and replace in all the calls explicitly during the conversion of Loadrunner scripts into Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am facing  the issue in the conversion of large LR scripts which has 3000 calls  into JMX,taking time consuming performing Regular Expression and replace in all the calls explicitly .

My expectation is it should capture the Regular expression  if the Load Runner script has.For ex :Session Key correlation. But Right now when I convert,it just converts calls  .

How can i overcome this?

Please advise me!

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. Avoid multiple distinct questions. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Naveen, What's wrong in my question? I think i have clearly mentioned what I am looking for

Comment: Multiple distinct questions and explain scenarios are not encouraged.

Comment: Someone might flag your question. Everything is for your good only.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Naveen!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Blazemeter article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter), you need to correlate manually or you need to use [Blazemeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-?utm_source=BM&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter).

> Once you have test script “skeleton”, you will most likely need to
> manually correlate dynamic values by using JMeter PostProcessors
> (Regular Expression Extractor, CSS/JQuery Extractor, etc).
>
> OR you can use the BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder instead of JMeter’s HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder can export
> tests in “SmartJMX” mode. This mode it will automatically detect any
> dynamic parameters and generate the relevant test logic to substitute
> hard-coded recorded values with the ones extracted from previous
> responses. This way, you won’t have to take any extra actions. See
> this [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80% article for further
> details](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80?utm_source=BM&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter).

Comment: Uhm, this question appears to be about LoadRunner, but the answer is a non-sequitur about JMETER

Comment: Hi, James. Asker trying to convert LR scripts to JMeter where he/she expecting autocorrelation in JMeter while converting which is not possible. I believe the answer is relevant.

Comment: An expectation on automagical correlation fails no matter the chosen platform

Comment: Asked expectation is loadrunner script has correlation, upon converting to JMeter; JMeter script has to create regular expression extractors automatically, which is not possible.